# Pentaho-kettle to write log in a file using java

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I have a kettle job and it's running successfully using java. But, kettle writing it's log into standard output (console). I want logs to be written in any file (.txt, .log). Is there any way to write logs in a file? And if possible with the user defined log file name.

Answer (score 0):

Run a job using command line argument using kitchen interface. There can specify the log file location and name.

Comment: But is there any way to create log file and write the logs inside that file using java?